# Best interpolating points for a Gaussian process regression

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, interpolation, active-learning

I have an unknown function $f(x)$, defined on a domain, that is modeling a perception function based on a human user response. I estimate it with a GP with mean $\mu$ and kernel $K$. I determine the hyperparameters of those functions with the minimization of the negative loglikelihood, performed on a starting training set. I would say that this training set can be considered as a set of interpolating points. I want to increment the training set iteratively and determine the best location so that a user can provide the function value at that point. I used GP regression because for every point I can compute the mean and the variance, and thus I have a measure of the uncertainty of the estimation. Based on those functions, I can define an acquisition function that tells me how informative every point is. Right now, my acquisition function is the GP variance, so the next location is just the one where the variance is peaking.

My question is: what are the options available here? How to orient the selection more to the exploration or more to the consolidation? Does it make sense to have the likelihood involved in the computation of the acquisition function? Note: I don't want to have the same location selected more than once and I would like to have the best interpolation on all the points of the domain.

I came across mutual information: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/contal14.pdf. Here, the assumption is that the problem is to find the maximum of $f$: $f(x^\star) = \max_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)$. Does the algorithm apply in my case anyway?

Answer (score 0):

An active learning/acquisition algorithm that samples only points corresponding to high uncertainty is, indeed, not the correct strategy.  Finding a correct balance between sampling *informative* points, and sampling *consolidating* (as you phrased it) points is a problem that does not have a clear answer.

However, several adhoc methods for achieving some kind of a balance do exist. One of my favourites works as follows. Start by computing the uncertainty over all candidate samples and then build a probability distribution that gives large weights to points that have large uncertainties in their predictions. Choose the points to add to your training set by sampling from this probability distribution. In such a way, points that have large uncertainties, i.e., informativ points, would still be added to your dataset because of their large weights. Points that have lower uncertainties but lie in dense regions, i.e., consolidating points, would also still be sampled because there are so many of them. This is the main idea behind the [stochastic query by forest algorithm](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v16/borisov11a), also presented [here](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/155/14/144109/957207/Active-learning-of-potential-energy-surfaces-of) in another context. There exist as well more principled ways to balance informativeness and representativeness (i.e., consolidating strategies), see, for example, [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2700408). However, in my experience, they don't really work better than adhoc strategies. Finally, note that you don't necessarily need to be using a Gaussian process to estimate uncertainty.

Comment: You are basically building another probability distribution weighted with the uncertainty values. That is a clever strategy! Of course, I think that exist a lot of strategies to make a prediction with an uncertainty value connected to it, I just picked up the Gaussian Processes because there's a lot of literature regarding them. I'll check the references, thank you very much!